# Possible to prevent telephone link detection in XAML WebView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 Universal App that's using a WebView control to load an intranet page on a kiosk. The WebView is automatically adding links to detected phone numbers on the page which launches a "Call" action that allows the user to choose an app (Chrome, Skype, etc.) and escape the kiosk mode application.

Is it possible to prevent the control from detecting these actions and adding in links?

[image: The auto detected tel link]

[image: The resulting Call / Contact action]

Comment: Have you found any solution?